# Display:none/block ordering

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dhtml, appendchild

I am learning JavaScript and trying to reorder elements from their original structure. For instance, if I had the following elements:

```
<p id="first">Hello</p>
<p id="second">Bye</p>
```

### The output would be:

Hello

Bye

---

### But I am trying to make the output:

Bye

Hello

---

What I am doing is giving each element an numeric id (the first element is given an id of 1, the second is 2, tenth is 10 and so on). Then I am using `document.getElementById()` and a for loop to place each element in an array and hiding the elements in order by using `array[i].style.display = none`. Then I am making the array visible in backwards order by using another for loop and doing 
`array(array.length-i).display = block`. But this is again returning in normal document order (i.e. *Hello* then *Bye* instead of *Bye* then *Hello*). **Why is that? What can I do instead?**

Here is the code:

```
<p id="1">a</p>  <!--UPLOADED FIRST -->
<p id="2">b</p>
<p id="3">c</p>  <!--UPLOADED LAST -->

<script type="text/javascript">    
var zana = [];

for(var i = 1;i<10;i++){ //inclusive not inclusive
    if(document.getElementById(i)==null) break;
    zana[i]=document.getElementById(i);
    console.log(zana[i]);
}    

/*now we have an array, Zana, of elements in which the 
last index elements are the ones we want first */

for(var i = 1;i<10;i++){
     if(zana[i]==null) break;
    zana[i].style.display = "none"; 

}
  //  alert(zana[1].innerHTML);
for(var i = 1; i<zana.length;i++){
 console.log(zana[zana.length-i]);
 zana[zana.length-i].style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

**EDIT:**

### I figured out how to do this by using document.createElement() instead. Here is the code in case anyone would like it/is reading this for future reference. Let me know if there is a more efficient way you can do this:

```
<p id="1">a</p>  <!--UPLOADED FIRST -->
<p id="2">b</p>
<p id="3">c</p>  <!--UPLOADED LAST -->

<script type="text/javascript">    
var zana = [];

for(var i = 1;i<10;i++){ //inclusive not inclusive
    if(document.getElementById(i)==null) break;
    zana[i]=document.getElementById(i);
    console.log(zana[i]);
}    

/*now we have an array, Zana, of elements in which the 
last index elements are the ones we want first */

for(var i = 1;i<10;i++){
     if(zana[i]==null) break;
    zana[i].style.display = "none"; 

}

  //  alert(zana[1].innerHTML);
for(var i = 1; i<zana.length;i++){
 var temp = document.createElement("p");
 var temptext = document.createTextNode((zana[zana.length-i]).innerHTML); 
 temp.appendChild(temptext);    
 document.body.appendChild(temp);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Because you just changed the sequence of rendering the elements and not the position.

Comment: Changing the position would involve more then just changing the CSS display property. You should completely move the elements. As a side note: HTML id's are not allowed to start with a number :-)

Comment: @WartClaes I'm not actually trying to use the CSS 'position' property because I don't want to take these elements out of normal document flow, as this might affect elements not included in what I am trying to do with reversing. Also I haven't really seen any docs that say I'm not allowed to order my id's with a number, and it's not giving me an error. Alternatively I guess I could just do id="_1" (id="_#")

Comment: "Using characters except ASCII letters and digits, '_', '-' and '.' may cause compatibility problems, as they weren't allowed in HTML 4. Though this restriction has been lifted in HTML 5, an ID should start with a letter for compatibility." - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)

Answer (score 0):

> ...this is again returning in normal document order (*Hello* then *Bye* instead of *Bye* then *Hello*). **Why is that?**

As was mentioned in the comments, the code merely set the display property in reverse order - it didn't actually reverse the order of the nodes.

> **What can I do instead?**

One way this could be achieved is to actually remove the nodes with [.remove()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove) and then in reverse order append them with [Node.appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild). See the example below, where the *reverse order* is achieved by setting the initial value if the iterator in the *for* loop to the length of the array and then decrementing instead of incrementing the value:

```
for (var i = zana.length; i > 0; i--) {
```

Also for this, we should check to ensure that the element at the given index is not [*null*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null) (or also [*undefined*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined)) but if it is, skip to the next iteration (with [continue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue)) instead of breaking out of the loop:

```
if (zana[i] == null) continue;
```

In the examples below, the functionality to reverse the paragraph tags has been moved into an event handler. Click the button labeled *Reverse order* to see the elements order reversed. The event handler also isn't added until the DOM is ready, utilizing [EventTarget.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) on the [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) object and waiting for the event [*DOMContentLoaded*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded). This avoids errors when accessing DOM elements before the DOM is ready.

Also the paragraph tags were moved into a containing *div* (i.e. `<div id="container"`) to isolate the elements to have their order reversed but you could leave them as childnodes of the body tag and utilize `document.body` when appending them back in the DOM.

```js
var zana = [];
//wait until the DOM is ready before interacting with DOM
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var container = document.getElementById('container');
  //only reverse when button is clicked
  document.getElementById('reverse').addEventListener('click', function(clickEvent) {
    for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) { //inclusive not inclusive
      if (document.getElementById(i) == null) break;
      zana[i] = document.getElementById(i);
    }

    /*now we have an array, Zana, of elements in which the 
    last index elements are the ones we want first */

    for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
      if (zana[i] == null) break;
      zana[i].remove();
    }
    for (var i = zana.length; i > 0; i--) {
      if (zana[i] == null) continue;
      container.appendChild(zana[i]);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p id="1">a</p>
  <!--UPLOADED FIRST -->
  <p id="2">b</p>
  <p id="3">c</p>
  <!--UPLOADED LAST -->
</div>
<button id="reverse">Reverse order</button>
```

Another option would be to reverse the array with [Array.reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) before iterating over the items:

```
zana.reverse();
for (var i = 0; i < zana.length ; i++) {
    //iterate over the items now in reverse order
```

```js
var zana = [];
//wait until the DOM is ready before interacting with DOM
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var container = document.getElementById('container');
  //only reverse when button is clicked
  document.getElementById('reverse').addEventListener('click', function(clickEvent) {
    for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) { //inclusive not inclusive
      if (document.getElementById(i) == null) break;
      zana[i] = document.getElementById(i);
    }

    /*now we have an array, Zana, of elements in which the 
    last index elements are the ones we want first */

    for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
      if (zana[i] == null) break;
      zana[i].remove();
    }
    zana.reverse();
    for (var i = 0; i < zana.length; i++) {
      if (zana[i] == null) continue;
      container.appendChild(zana[i]);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p id="1">a</p>
  <!--UPLOADED FIRST -->
  <p id="2">b</p>
  <p id="3">c</p>
  <!--UPLOADED LAST -->
</div>
<button id="reverse">Reverse order</button>
```

Or for an even simpler approach (presuming we only need to work with sibling elements and not sub-elements), iterate over the childNodes of the container and call [Node.insertBefore()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore), passing the first child node as the second argument (the node to insert the current element before). You will also notice that the code below is a functional approach with [Array.forach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). That way we don't have to store the elements in an array manually, create a counter/iterator variable to iterate and then index into the array with that variable. Also, this will iterate over the elements once instead of three times.

```js
//wait until the DOM is ready before interacting with DOM
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var container = document.getElementById('container');
  //only reverse when button is clicked
  document.getElementById('reverse').addEventListener('click', function(clickEvent) {
    container.childNodes.forEach(function(childNode) {
      if (childNode.previousSibling) {
        container.insertBefore(childNode, container.firstChild);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p id="1">a</p>
  <!--UPLOADED FIRST -->
  <p id="2">b</p>
  <p id="3">c</p>
  <!--UPLOADED LAST -->
</div>
<button id="reverse">Reverse order</button>
```